# ag grid not passing context to child component in angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm using Ag-grid version 26.2.0 in my angular project. I've referred to the official documentation and implemented the code as they have suggested to pass the parent context to the child components. I've followed all the steps, but getting the parent context as undefined.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.. Any help is appreciated.

Below are the code snippets:

parent component:

```
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
  public frameworkComponents;
  context: any = { comp: this};
...

constructor(){
this.context = { parent: this };
}
...

}
```

Component html:

```
...

    <ag-grid-angular [context]="context" [columnDefs]="savedCartColumns" [rowData]="savedProducts" [pagination]="true"
      [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents" [paginationPageSize]="itemsPerPage"
      [suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns]="true" [enableCellTextSelection]="true" [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
      [suppressExcelExport]="false" [suppressContextMenu]="false" [popupParent]="popupParent"
      class="ag-theme-balham saved-cart" style="width: 100%; height: 550px" (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"></ag-grid-angular>

...
```

Child component:

```
import { ICellRendererParams } from 'ag-grid-community';
...
export class ManageCartComponent {
  private params: ICellRendererParams;
  componentParent: any;
...

  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.componentParent = params.context.parent;
  }
```

Error at runtime:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'parent')
    at ManageCartComponent.push.gxGq.ManageCartComponent.agInit (manageCart.component.ts:50:43)
```

Comment: What do you get if you log the `params.context`? I guess it has `comp` instead of `parent`.

Comment: @MishaMashina, nope, I've tried with the different name for the parent component. If you see, I've reinitialized the context with 'parent' property. My problem is params.context itself is coming as undefined. params.parent gives property not exists error, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I missed to add this piece of code in the right aggrid instance as I have two aggrid instances in one page:

```
context="context"
```

After adding this, the child component gets the parent's context as expected!